# Spy Function Call in Subscription callback - angular unit test

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, ngrx

how can I test if a specific function was called inside the subscribe block of a observable?

Scenario is the following:

```
private openMemberPopup(): void {
    this.memberDialogRef = this.dialogRef.open(MemberPopupComponent, { width: '800px' });
    this.memberDialogRef.componentInstance.onMemberAdded.subscribe(member => {
      this.store.dispatch(new CreateMemberAction({ member })); <-- this line should be tested
    });
  }
```

I would like to test the method above, which is opening a material dialog. Then I subscribe to a EventEmitter of the Popup component. In the next callback, I dispatch a new NGRX-Action.

The following approach does not work:

```
it('should dispatch CreateMemberAction', async () => {
      const dialogRef = component.dialogRef;

      // tslint:disable-next-line:no-object-literal-type-assertion
      const member = {} as Member;
      const spyOnRef = spyOn(dialogRef, 'open').and.returnValue({
        componentInstance: {
          onMemberAdded: hot('-a-|', { a: member })
        }
      });

      const store = TestBed.get(Store);
      const spy = spyOn(store, 'dispatch');
      const expected = new CreateMemberAction({ member });

      component['openAddMemberPopup']();

      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expected);
    });
```

Error Message is:

> Expected spy dispatch to have been called with [ CreateMemberAction({
>   payload: Object({ member: Object({  }) }), type: '[Member] Create
>   Member' }) ] but it was never called.

Any hints or best practices? Thank you

Comment: Hi, where are you calling the function openMemberPopup?

Comment: Hey did you end up figuring out what the issue was @fabi_k